# New Pycharm project with Anaconda needs to install pip packages everytime

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I'm currently using Windows 10, and installed Pycharm and Anaconda on it in order to run Tensorflow.  Everything is working well, I can select conda interpreter and then use the following command to install and run tensorflow.

`pip.main(['install', 'tensorflow'])`

My only problem is, everytime I create a new project in pycharm, I need to do this installation command again.  Is there a more permanent method to do the installation in my case?

Thanks.

EDIT:I installed the package inside Pycharm as shown in this video
[Install Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83vR1Nz3dHA)

Comment: From the command line, `activate` the virtualenv you use with PyCharm and then either `pip install tensorflow` or `conda install tensorflow`

Comment: are you referring to windows command line?  Because I installed by opening python console in Pycharm, and entered the commands from there.  Trying pip install tensorflow there does not work.

Comment: First create a virtualenv: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands  Then install `tensorflow` inside the virtualenv https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows. Then configure Pycharm to use this virtualenv: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html.html. The 2 first steps should be done in the command line (windows/linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to build a TensorFlow virtual environment in Anaconda Navigator in the anaconda3 directory.As shown in the figure:[anaconda navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbX39.jpg),[environment about tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4wlG.jpg).You can create a Tensorflow environment on the command line and install pycharm as a pip in this environment. This will allow you to use Tensorflow in pycharm.The code is as follows:

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

This is a Chinese version of the installation instructions for TensorFlow + pycharm.[installation instructions](https://blog.csdn.net/lwplwf/article/details/54896088)